# Flex: How to access properties of component in dynamic creation?

Tags: apache-flex, properties, components

I have a component which is created dynamically. I want to access the properties on it.

for example i create a vbox and i want to access the text font or gap of the component

var MyVBox: VBox = new VBox;
  MyPanel.addChild(MyVBox);

How should it be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All properties and methods are accessed with "." (dot) notation.

Example:

```
myVBox.width = 400;
```

Styles are set using the setStyle() method. In your case that would be

```
myVBox.setStyle("fontFamily", "arial");
myVBox.setStyle("verticalGap", 20);
```

Check the docs at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/ for the available properties and styles of each component.

Answer (score 0):

The thing to remember when using ActionScript instead of MXML is that the style properties are not accessed as properties on the object but through the getStyle("propertyName") method. Font is a style for example.

Comment: i am new in ActionScript. I code delphi before and the code is very  different. I started study flex 2 weeks from now. By the way how should it be done? Can u give me an example code? thank you for your quick response